# Setting jpf in eclipse and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, jpf

I'm trying to make java path finder work with my test examples, using the verify plugin from eclipse doesn't seem to work for some reason, I'm using then run-JPF method.
JPF seems to work until I try to use some external class like: gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.Verify that he doesn't seem to find. I've tried adding it in the classpath of the run method, but still I've the same issue, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was about using java 1.8, switching to 1.7 solved everything.